# Remove old entry from ListView when Firebase is updated

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im struggling a little with my code. I have searched and tried many methods. My aim is remove the previous entry that Firebase has provided to my app, the firebase data is coming from an embedded device.I want to replace the value in my android app.

Firebase is working ok, The app will display the new value provided by firebase but will not delete the previous entry.

I still have plenty to do but want to fix the basics before moving on.

So basically the OnChildChanged will display new firebase entries, i just want the previous entry deleted from the Android Application when a new value comes in from Firebase.

I have looked into removeValue and setValue with no avail

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference fDatabase;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    fDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.remove(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I found a solution, quite simple, i added adapter.clear to the OnChildChanged

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        list.remove(value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.add(value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Looks like when you assign `value` it's getting the new entry, so when you call `list.remove` it isn't removing the old entry since it's actually trying to remove any instance of the new entry.

See if there's any way you can map the old entry to the new entry so the list knows what to remove since the content of `value` is different between old and new.